# Error in Textview

Tags: android, xml, textview

I'm getting the error `Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Element type "TextView" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" 
     or "/>".
    - error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)`

For the following xml file:

The recent changes I made was to add the line android:layout_below to all of the textviews except one because otherwise the textviews ran into each other.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <!-- can have image view in here as well -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#CC0033"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#3399FF"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/day1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contact"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#3399FF"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/from1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/day1"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#3399FF"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/to1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/from1"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#3399FF"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/day2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/to1"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#3399FF"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/from2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/day2"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#3399FF"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/to2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/from2"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#3399FF"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Help!

**Additional Information:**

The xml file is for a CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter public class I created for my ListView.

**UPDATE**

So I took out the comment, replaced the extra pluses and took out the extra space in the listview @id/name, one error is gone, the remaining one is `error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)`

Comment: try cleaning the project

Comment: @mani- I already have

Comment: is this all your xml file?

Comment: well i don't see here a issue also I try your code and is working fine

Comment: I tried myself and it also works for me. Seems fine.

Comment: @Ahmed Zafar Try to remove comment from layout.

Comment: @dymmeh- that is extremely weird. I'll try to restart eclipse and see what happens.

Comment: @x90- tried that as well and cleaned project. right now restarting eclipse again. will try without comment again.

Comment: @AhmedZafar This might be a weird comment, but see what happens if you try and remove the a newline space that is there in `android:id="@+id/name" ` `TextView` ? Few time it happens with me and gives error due to extra space, not sure why.

Comment: @shobhit- Not weird at all I'll try that

Comment: I pasted this into my android app and it worked fine (no compilation errors or anything) I'm thinking the problem isn't directly inside this XML

Comment: @hyrum- my eclipse is still loading at the moment. thanks for the try. i'll update you guys on what happens. and yes that is a possibility

Comment: Okay so I tried all of the above. Error is still there. How can the error be outside the xml file? I have a CustomListViewAdapter. Can that cause the error?

Comment: One error is gone, one remains

Comment: So what do you still have?

Comment: @hyrum- this: `error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)`

Comment: This is extremely annoying... I changed the xml file and it threw the errors but apparently it's compiling on other systems.

Comment: And now, I cut and pasted back the entire text and the error changed: `Element type "TextView" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".`

Comment: Okay so I got it to work by removing `paddingLeft` from @id/name, I don't know how it got there and I don't know why it was throwing errors. If anyone knows please do let me know. My bad, apparently there was a line in there that does not show on over here. :/

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_below="@+id/name"
```

!!! as i remember, to mention an id it is written like this

```
android:layout_below="@id/name"
```

but any way, just try this first, maybe i'm wrong, and i'll try to find out

Comment: thank you but I tried it. I'll try changing all of it and let you know